# how to define a function outside of a class

Tags: c++

I need a function that uses two or more classes from the same header, but the function itself should not belong to any other class. But the function could be placed in the header since it is more meaningful that way.

For this in C++ when I try to call the function I get the error

> undefined reference to f( )
> error: ld returned 1 exit status

my header is something like:

```
class A{...};
class B{...};
int f(){...} // f uses A and B
```

Making it `static` did not work. So is there a workaround this?

Comment: How exactly does `f` use `A` and `B`? Would be nice if we could possibly see a [mcve]. Also is `ld` really not showing any error message before `error: ld returned 1 exit status`?

Comment: I assume you have a multiple definition error? It would help to have the whole error copy/pasted into your question along with an example of the code that produces it. Chances are you need to mark that function inline or consider keeping the prototype in the header and the implementation in a cpp file.

Comment: It probably means you haven't included the object file that *defines* (implements) `f()` in the link.   If you had it defined (non-`inline`) in a header file, and included that header file in more than one source file, then the error would be about `f()` being defined multiple times (assuming all the corresponding object files included in the link).

Answer (score 3):

Did you include the header file in the implementation file?

Here is an example that might help you:

**hi.h**

```
#ifndef HI_H_
#define HI_H_

class A {
 public:
  static void foo() {}  // making it static for simplity in this example
};

class B {
 public:
  static void foo() {}  // ditto
};

int add(int a, int b);  // Declaration

#endif  // HI_H_
```

**hi.cc**

```
#include "hi.h"

int f() {
  A::foo();
  B::foo();
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  f();
}
```